# Is it possible to do "Active" mode FTP using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Due to some firewall issues, we need to do FTP using "active" mode (i.e. not by initiating a `PASV` command).

Currently, we're using code along the lines of:

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

But this seems to default to using passive mode; Can we influence this to force it to upload using active mode (in the same way that the command line ftp client does)?

Comment: .Net Reflector will tell you the answer. :)  Much easier are the MSDN docs though.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest_members(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, set the [UsePassive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property to false.

```
request.UsePassive = false;
```

Comment: Doh. Less than brilliant default that. And there was me looking for a `Mode` property/enum.

Comment: Sometimes, the solution is so simple that you feel kinda dumb when you see it. This is one of those times where I feel kinda dumb ;)